# Two adjectives with different meaning for the same noun

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

> 1. Summer and Winter **vacation** are compulsory in our schools.
> 2. Summer and Winter **vacations** are compulsory in our schools.

which one is correct? As summer vacation and winter vacation are different, shouldn’t we use plural word “vacations”?

Comment: Spelling: compuls**o**ry.

Comment: Edited @MichaelHarvey

Comment: Yes, I would make it plural.

Comment: @KateBunting. Are you native speaker?

Comment: Certainly I am!

Comment: Plural, because the two seasons are mentioned.